# Como colar um dataframe sobre uma planilha pré-formatada em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-excel, pandas

Tenho um template pré-formatado no Excel dessa forma. [image: template.xlsx]

Gostaria de colar valores de um dataframe no pandas sobre essas células, criando um novo arquivo formatado com valores e mantendo o arquivo original. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Dados1': ['Ola','tudo','bom']})

#carrego o Excel com o template pré-formatado 'template.xlsx'
book = load_workbook('template.xlsx')

#defino o writer para escrever em um novo arquivo 'arquivo_editado.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('arquivo_editado.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

#incluo a formatação no writer
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

#Escrevo com o .to_excel() do pandas
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

# para escrever só os valores em um lugar específico:
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Fontes:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas

Comment: Perfeito! Eu já tinha visto esse segundo link que você enviou, mas não estava conseguindo adequar a esse exato problema. Obrigado!

Comment: Infelizmente o pandas buga algumas bordas (alguns contornos simplesmente somem)... Acho que vou ter que corrigí-las hard-coded mesmo, mas sua resposta já fez 95% do que eu precisava.

Comment: Excelente, mas o meu arquivo tem varias abas, eu queria colocar os dados do dataframe em uma aba especifica, tem como?

Comment: Na função `df.to_excel()`, acredito que seja só trocar a string `'Sheet1'` pelo nome da aba.

Comment: Fiz essa tentativa, não deu certo

Answer (score -2):

Talvez se você adicionar `sheet= ' '`  em `book = load_workbook('template.xlsx')` funcione, porém eu não testei

desse jeito:

```
book = load_workbook('template.xlsx', sheet = 'nome_da_aba')
```

da mesma maneira como se fosse ler um Excel normalmente no pandas.

```
pd.read_excel('arquivo.xlsx', sheet = 'nome_da_aba', engine = 'openpyxl')
```

Comment: O nome correto do parâmetro, na função [pandas.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), é `sheet_name`.